# React Build Can not server page when user refresh on a route

Tags: reactjs, deployment, serve

I build my react app using `npm run-script build` and every things is alright .

When i navigate to production site and navigate to a route and refresh on the page with F5 , unexpected error showed up :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

I got this error on first publish and i figure out the problem is in package`package.json` homepage property , I changed it to `"homepage": "."` and sites is OK . But in routes everything breaks .

I think `node serve` can not server index.html on sub routes.

any suggestion ??

EDIT::

Also I try express server in following link :

```
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/
```

but nothing changes . same error on refresh in routes.

Also my images urls breaks . Why browser append a prefix at start of url ?!

for example image src is : `./static/media/aaa.4dccf6e3.webp` but browser looks for `/admin/static/media/aaa.4dccf6e3.webp`

in development system everything is alright!

Comment: Can you post the express server code that you have tried?

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings you can see it here : https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#other-solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem . 
homepage property in package.json . i just clean the value and everything get ok.

the problem happens because homepage property value is "." and every address for js, css and images prefix with dot . and when you are in middle of route in client , browser fetch these files from wrong address.